# 'Client' object has no attribute 'sms'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm an intro to programming student. The following code is supposed to send a text message to my phone, but it is giving me the error message:

> 'Client' object has no attribute 'sms'

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
auth_token = "42xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.sms.messages.create(
    body="Hello!",
    to="+19545555555", # Replace with your phone number
    from_="+17725555555") # Replace with your twilio number
print message.sid
```

Comment: I found the answer in my class forum. For others with the same problem, the line that says:
message = client.sms.message.create(
should read:
message = client.message.create(

Answer (score 0):

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
auth_token = "42xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    body="Hello!",
    to="+19545555555", # Replace with your phone number
    from_="+17725555555") # Replace with your twilio number
print message.sid
```

Try this. It there shouldn't be an `sms`